# df shows wrong diskspace raspberry pi

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, raspberry-pi

I used to have a Raspberry Pi Model B+ with an 8GB card and NOOBS, now I upgraded to a card with 32GB, but my df -h command outputs this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       5.7G  5.0G  358M  94% /
devtmpfs        481M     0  481M   0% /dev
tmpfs           486M     0  486M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           486M   13M  473M   3% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           486M     0  486M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p6   68M   21M   48M  31% /boot
tmpfs            98M     0   98M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/mmcblk0p5   30M  398K   28M   2% /media/pi/SETTINGS
```

It says the /dev/root fylesystem is 5.7GB, but shoudn't it be bigger?

I've tried `sudo raspi-config` filesystem expand but it says it already is expandes. Am I just understanding something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Your card is probably `/dev/mmcblk0` and `/dev/root` is just a symlink to `/dev/mmcblk0p1` or so. Since there is `/dev/mmcblk0p5`, I expect many partitions to exist and take space from the 8 GB pool. What is the output of `ls -l /dev/root`? `gdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0`? `swapon`? (with `sudo` if needed). Please respond by [edit]ing the question.

Comment: Did you just copy the old card to the new one using `dd` or similar? If so you need to resize the partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check if this command present in your OS or not `resize2fs`

If present, use below command to refresh value

```
resize2fs /dev/root
```

If you are using different OS, Please find alternative command of `resize2fs` which will help you to refresh values.